# Possible to add a local server as Virtual SMTP inside another server?

Tags: windows, iis, smtp

I wounder if is possible to add a virtual SMTP server a local server?

I have created a SMTP server on a server, I wonder if it's possible to create a virtual smtp on another server that is local?

Comment: You have a far better chance of getting an answer to this by asking on StackOverflow's sister site ServerFault.com: http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that its not possible.